# Visual Studio - VB.net File in Use Exception 0x80070020

Tags: vb.net, exception

I have been working on this issue for over a month and have tried everything I have found in forums. Desperately need help.

**Background:**

1 - I recently started using a brand new PC (windows 10)

2 - I am running the exact same VS2019 version as previous PC

3 - This program is form that contains many checkboxes and text boxes. The user makes selections and enters information on the form then they save it. When it saves, I write the state of every control to a text file (aka .enc extension) using streamwriter. When a user then opens the form again it uses streamreader to open that same text file and set the state of every control on the form so the user can see what was previously entered.

4 - The text file is on a shared network, but when examining the file from the network management it does not show as 'in use' by any user including myself.

This program has been running for several years and there have been no changes to the IT infrastructure. Problem only exists for my PC.

**Issue:**

• When I open an existing project and make NO changes to it and run the program via debug or release and run the exe everything works fine

• As soon as I make ANY change to the source code (including something as simple as adding a comment character), it will throw an exception which I have at the very end of this post.

• The exception being thrown is tricky because it is most definitely not related to disposal of the stream (from a source code perspective). See Item A below

• When I try to modify or delete the text file through windows explorer it gives me a "file in use" message. When I use another PC to try to delete this file, it works without saying "file in use".

• As far as I suspect, there is something going on with a very deep level aspect of the compiler.

• To be clear, this is the issue: Run the program (creates a text file), no issue there. Then I wait, run the program again and then it crashes when trying to load that same text file. When I look at the text file through windows explorer it is 'in use'.

**What I have tried:**

A) I have tried both methods of disposing streamwriter and streamreader... stream.Close() method as well as  using stream Using ... End Using method. See code snippets below.

B) I have used a colleagues PC to run the exact same source project via debug as well as a released exe, and it causes NO issues.

C) I have tried using processMonitor and processExplorer to search for the text file to find a related process or .dll that is causing the hold up. It never shows up in process dumps.

D) Disabling antivirus

**E) Running on another PC. **This works.**

F) Compiling exe on another PC then running from my PC **Get same Error

G) Repair and re-install of VS

H) safe mode

I have read through hundreds of forum posts and tried almost every suggestion. If you have any ideas and can help me I would much appreciate it, you would be an absolute legend if you were able to figure this out.

**Code:**

**Method 1**

```
Dim filewriter As System.IO.StreamWriter

filewriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(dirNewENC & newfile, True)
filewriter.WriteLine("shortcutCreated=" & shortcutCreated)
filewriter.WriteLine("shortcutPath=" & shortcutPath)
...
filewriter.Close()
```

**Method 2**

```
Using filewriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(dirNewENC & newfile, True)
filewriter.WriteLine("shortcutCreated=" & shortcutCreated)
filewriter.WriteLine("shortcutPath=" & shortcutPath)
...
End Using
```

**Exception Detail:**

> System.IO.IOException
> HResult=0x80070020
> Message=The process cannot access the file '\affs01\Shared\Sales\Quotes\ENC\TEST8%01%TEST%Q99999998%44456%.enc' because it is being used by another process.
> Source=mscorlib
> StackTrace:
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
> at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
> at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
> at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
> at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks)
> at Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(String file, Encoding encoding)
> at Microsoft.VisualBasic.MyServices.FileSystemProxy.OpenTextFileReader(String file)
> at Order_Entry.GlobalSubs.checkOrderType() in C:\Users\RB\OneDrive\Code\repos\Order Entry\Order Entry\GlobalSubs.vb:line 6348
> at Order_Entry.frm_NewEntry.btn_searchQuote_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\RB\OneDrive\Code\repos\Order Entry\Order Entry\frm_NewEntry.vb:line 152
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Button.PerformClick()
> at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
> at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessMessage(Message& msg)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessControlMessageInternal(Control target, Message& msg)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.PreTranslateMessage(MSG& msg)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FPreTranslateMessage(MSG& msg)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext        context)
> at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
> at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
> at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
> at Order_Entry.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in :line 83

Comment: The fastest way to fix it is likely to be to reinstall Windows. Pick your favourite option: [Reset vs Refresh vs Clean install vs In-place Upgrade vs Cloud Reset vs Fresh Start in Windows](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fresh-start-reset-refresh-clean-install).

Comment: To me, attempted solution F) rules out anything in the compiler, of course if you compile on your machine, copy to a working PC it will confirm it.  This would lead me to think three possible causes.  1) Your windows environment, reinstall/reset may fix.  2) the permissions on the folder where this text file is located needs to be re-set.  3) There have been Windows updates over the years that really mess with basic things like sharing and what was simple now isn't.  All in all, sounds very environmental and possible out of scope for this forum

Answer (score 0):

Along with @Andrew Morton and @Hursey mentioned, I bit the bullet and wiped the PC with a clean reinstall.

Can happily (in one sense) report that the issue is resolved.

Thank you.

...now to get all my apps back.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).